# Ruby webdriver doesn't navigate in Chrome

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, watir-webdriver

I have just finished setting up the latest versions of Ruby (Ruby 2.0.0-p451 (x64)) and Watir.  I have downloaded both the selenium web driver gem and the watir webdriver gem, both installed successfully.  I then got the Ruby dev kit, installed that and it installed fine.  Lastly, I got the latest version (2.9) of chromedriver.exe and placed it in the bin directory for ruby.

I can start Chrome from a Watir script but I can't navigate to any URL.  When Chrome opens a new instance it has one tab and in the URL all it says is "data:,", the page is completely blank.  I have used examples and this one works with Firefox but not Chrome

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
b.goto 'bit.ly/watir-webdriver-demo'
b.text_field(:id => 'entry_0').set 'your name'
b.select_list(:id => 'entry_1').select 'Ruby'
b.select_list(:id => 'entry_1').selected? 'Ruby'
b.button(:name => 'submit').click
b.text.include? 'Thank you'
```

(that example came from http://watirwebdriver.com/)

If I remove ":chrome" from the end of the second line, Firefox opens and navigates to the URL as I'd expect, but can't get that to work in Chrome.

If I use the selenium-webdriver with Chrome I get the exact same result:  Chrome opens, it has "data:," in the URL and doesn't navigate to the URL in the script.

I also tried this in the Ruby 1.9.3-p545 version of Ruby and I get the exact same result, so I uninstalled that and am now using the 2.0.0 version of Ruby.

How can I get my script to open chrome and navigate to a URL?

Comment: What version of Chrome?

Comment: I am not at that computer now (won't be until this evening) so I can't get you the specific number but I did check for updates in Chrome and it said I had the latest version, no updates necessary.

Comment: @Baub , Did you solve this? I got this problem as well !